# SPSS GENLIN Generating Exp(B) and CI for pooled data

Tags: r, spss

Is there any way I can modify the syntax or utilize R to have SPSS GENLIN function generate exp(B) and 95% CI for pooled data after multiple imputation? Current syntax is shown below. The (EXPONENTIATED) after SUMMARY in the syntax does the exp(B) and CI for every other imputation, but not the pooled data. Output is also shown, but I cropped the image to only show 1 of 30 imputations.

```
* Generalized Estimating Equations. 
GENLIN AnyMinorComp (REFERENCE=FIRST) BY Preop_Ambulation (ORDER=DESCENDING) WITH Age 
  /MODEL Preop_Ambulation Age INTERCEPT=YES 
 DISTRIBUTION=BINOMIAL LINK=LOGIT 
  /CRITERIA METHOD=FISHER(1) SCALE=1 MAXITERATIONS=100 MAXSTEPHALVING=5 PCONVERGE=1E-006(ABSOLUTE) 
    SINGULAR=1E-012 ANALYSISTYPE=3(WALD) CILEVEL=95 LIKELIHOOD=FULL 
  /REPEATED SUBJECT=Study_ID WITHINSUBJECT=Site_Code SORT=YES CORRTYPE=INDEPENDENT ADJUSTCORR=YES 
    COVB=ROBUST MAXITERATIONS=100 PCONVERGE=1e-006(ABSOLUTE) UPDATECORR=1 
  /MISSING CLASSMISSING=EXCLUDE 
  /PRINT CPS DESCRIPTIVES MODELINFO FIT SUMMARY SOLUTION (EXPONENTIATED).
```

[image]

Comment: I've looked up the GENLIN function and from what I can tell, it uses generalized estimating equations (GEEs) to model structured data (i.e. the kind of data that's most often dealt with mixed effects models). To do GEEs, you can use the `gee` package. As for multiple imputations, there are a lot of ways to do it in R, with the most popular being the `mice` package, however, it's also possible to do imputation with random forests, K nearest neighbours, etc...

Comment: Overall, what you're asking for sounds definitely feasible, however, you should first try to do some coding on your own first and come to Stack Overflow if you get stuck.

Comment: @AdamB. Thank you for the response - I have done the multiple imputations and ran a GEE; however, the calculations for Exp(B) and its confidence intervals are not done for pooled data for whatever reason. I'd like to know if anyone more skilled than I knows of a modification I can make to the syntax to have the calculation done for the pooled data (the calculation is e^[B and Lower/Upper values])

I attempted to modify the syntax by adding (Exponentiated) at the end of the query but it only does it for the imputations and original data; not the pooled

Comment: What exactly is the pooled data in this context? If all you need is to take the exponentiated slope, upper CI, and lower CI from the fitted model, then you should be able to those values out of the model summary and then exponentiate them using the `exp()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DATASET DECLARE  temp.
OMS
  /SELECT TABLES
  /IF COMMANDS=['Generalized Linear Models'] SUBTYPES=['Parameter Estimates']
  /DESTINATION FORMAT=SAV NUMBERED=TableNumber_ OUTFILE='temp' VIEWER=YES.
GENLIN AnyMinorComp (REFERENCE=FIRST) BY Preop_Ambulation (ORDER=DESCENDING) WITH Age
  /MODEL Preop_Ambulation Age INTERCEPT=YES DISTRIBUTION=BINOMIAL LINK=LOGIT 
  /CRITERIA METHOD=FISHER(1) SCALE=1 MAXITERATIONS=100 MAXSTEPHALVING=5 PCONVERGE=1E-006(ABSOLUTE) SINGULAR=1E-012 ANALYSISTYPE=3(WALD) CILEVEL=95 LIKELIHOOD=FULL
  /REPEATED SUBJECT=Study_ID WITHINSUBJECT=Site_Code SORT=YES CORRTYPE=INDEPENDENT ADJUSTCORR=YES 
    COVB=ROBUST MAXITERATIONS=100 PCONVERGE=1e-006(ABSOLUTE) UPDATECORR=1
  /MISSING CLASSMISSING=EXCLUDE
  /PRINT CPS DESCRIPTIVES MODELINFO FIT SUMMARY SOLUTION (EXPONENTIATED).
OMSEND.
DATASET ACTIVATE temp.
COMPUTE ExpB=EXP(B).
COMPUTE Lower_A=EXP(Lower).
COMPUTE Upper_A=EXP(Upper).
EXECUTE.
```

This won't change the output, but in the newly created dataset it will do the calculations.